# svn commit fails upon trying to access nonexistent directory /home/.svn

Tags: svn, nfs

svn commit failed form me with the following error:

```
user@host> svn commit
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't open file '/home/.svn/entries': Input/output error
```

Now, the first problem here is that svn should look for
/home/user/.svn
and I don't know why it bothers with looking for the nonexistent
/home/.svn

The input/output error is not related to svn

```
user@host> ls /home/.svn
ls: /home/.svn: Input/output error
```

it is just a consequence of the NFS mounting system.
Unfortunately I have little control on how that's set up.

Anyway the question:
How do I explicitely tell svn where to look for the .svn file?
If that's not possible, how do I work around this?

svn version: 1.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found how to solve this (even though this is not a nice solution).

I just wiped out the entire tree of my project, including /home/user/.svn

Then re-checkout the whole project.

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your working copy in /home/? Then SVN will be looking for it in /home/.svn. If this tree was copied to a new location you may want to redo your svn checkout to get the paths cleaned up. I'm not sure if a svn clean will fix the paths for you (I usually do a checkout to keep it clean).

Comment: no, I am issuing "svn commit" inside the directory where modified files reside. Issuing svn cleanup did not solve the issue.